# Controlling external camera with Android smartphone

Tags: android, camera, usb

I would like to write an Android app to pass commands to an external camera whose SDK is available from the manufacturer's website. The SDK is C-based and the camera I/O is done through a mini-USB or mini-HDMI ports. This is a two part question:

- Can Android-based smartphones send commands to external USB devices? I do know that they can access data from an external USB device.
- Will C wrappers for Java (that work on laptops) work on Android-based smartphone?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Can Android-based smartphones send commands to external USB
>   devices? I do know that they can access data from an external USB
>   device.

A: Sure, as long as the device is connected via the Android USB port :)

> Q: Will C ... work on Android-based smartphone?

A: With much effort, you can interface Java and C on android (analogous to JNI on other platforms).  Look at the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) docs for more details.

> Q: Can I interface a binary C language library that's probably written
>   for Windows, in i386 object code, from Java, on Android, running an
>   ARM CPU?

A: Nope.  It's more than just a different language.  You're also dealing with a different platform, different object formats, and a completely different CPU architecture.

Your best bet is if the vendor can provide either a USB-level or message-level interface to the device.  You're pretty much SOL with a binary .dll or .lib library interface.